# Como pegar um texto de um textfield com várias linhas em uma lista com um item por linha

Tags: flutter

Gostaria de saber se tem alguma forma de pegar um texto de um textfield e transformá-lo em uma lista.

Texto com um item em cada linha.

A

B

C

D

Lista = [‘A’, ‘B’, ‘C’, ‘D’]

Tentei usar um for mas não sei a melhor forma de identificar que a linha acabou e vão iniciar a outra.

Comment: Sua pergunta ficou um pouco confusa... Você quer, por exemplo, digitar algo no TextField e ao clicar em um botão, inserir o registro em uma lista? Se você nos der um exemplo do que já fez podemos te ajudar, pois se for como falei, é possível sim e bem simples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nesse caso o split é dado nos espaços entre cada palavra. No seu caso pode ser diferente. Você pode esclarecer sua dúvida melhor em: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/String/split.html

```
var string = "Olá mundo!";
string.split(" ");   

//resultado
['Olá','mundo!']
```

Comment: Vacilei de não ter pesquisado o split em dart/flutter, muito obrigado!

Comment: de nada Fernando, fico feliz em ter ajudado! Ressalto aqui a importância da documentação, para qualquer tecnologia que você venha a utilizar. Sucesso!

Comment: Valeu mesmo pela resposta e pela dica abs.

Answer (score 1):

Digamos que este seja o seu TextField

```
TextField(
  keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
  maxLines: 10,
);
```

Você pode obter o valor dele adicionando um controller de tipo `TextEditingController`, ou simplemente adicionando uma `callback` ao metodo `onChanged`, pra facilitar as coisas vamos adicionar a `callback`

```
TextField(
  keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
  maxLines: 10,
  onChanged: (novoTexto) {}
);
```

Como já sugerido pela resposta do João Monteiro, você precisa fazer um [split](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/String/split.html) na variável que contém o seu texto, que no seu caso seria por linha, para isso você pode usar o caractere `\n`, estão ficaria:

```
onChanged: (novoTexto) {
  var lista = novoTexto.split('\n');
}
```

Deste modo cada vez que o valor do seu input mudar, o metodo `onChanged` será chamado com a função que você passou, dentro desta você está "divindo" o texto em uma lista de textos, cada entrada desta lista corresponde a uma linha do texto;

Comment: Cara era exatamento isso, muito obrigado! Já havia usado o split mas em python, vacilada rs. De qualquer forma valeu mesmo.